# Adding junit maven dependency giving error at cucumber runner file

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber

Adding below Junit dependency in maven pom.xml file do not show any cucumberrunner.java file

```
But once i add scope like below
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        **<scope>test</scope>** 
    </dependency>
it starts giving error in cucumberrunner.java file 
[![enter code here][1]][1]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By adding scope `test` you're only putting JUnit on the classpath when executing from `src/test`. I guess your runner class is in `src/main`.

Comment: my check my updated ques

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber framework is adding JUnit as transitive dependency and this is probably making some conflicts with it.
Why do you want to add JUnit 4.12 as a separate dependency?